# How to get started with battery replacement in a bluetooth speaker?

Tags: batteries, soldering

I have a bluetooth speaker with a faulty battery ([this model](http://www.divoom.com/product/voombox-outdoor.html)). I'd like to replace it but I have very limited experience with this kind of repair work. To get started, I'd like to

1. identify what type of replacement I need,
2. identify what kind of tools I'll need to use.

As for point 1. my issue is that I'm not sure what to look for when replacing a battery. **What specs are important here?**

As for point 2. I intend to get an antistatic wristband and a mat to make sure I don't zap anything in the speaker, but I'm not totally sure I need it. **Do I need antistatic protection in this case?** Also, I'm not sure whether soldering might be required. **Is it likely that I'll need to solder stuff?**

Comment: Find the battery model number and buy another battery with the same model number

Comment: In the page you cite it says " ... Battery Capacity: 3600 mAh
Battery Voltage: 3.7 V ..." - This is (with 99.9% probability) a Lithium Ion or Lithium Polymer single cell battery. A battery of either type of about the same capacity will probably work. This may be a single cylindrical 18650 LiIon battery or a "flat" LiPo battery. Any battery in the 3000 - 4200 mAh capacity range is probably OK. There is a small chance that there will be charging issues with a different bttery but this is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two battery specifications you'll need to match:

1. [Nominal voltage](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/battery-technologies/all)
2. Max current draw

The nominal voltage is the average voltage a cell has when charged. For a single cell Li-Ion battery it's around 3.7V *but* we don't know how the battery pack is made up. If it's two cells in parallel or some other kind of configuration. The max current draw is how much current the battery would be expected to produce under full load.

Usually, when you dismount the unit this information is printed on the battery pack. If it's not you'll have to look for a replacement battery (contact their support for the model number) and just use that.

I didn't say you had to match the [capacity](https://www.pololu.com/blog/2/understanding-battery-capacity-ah-is-not-a) (stock capacity is 3600mAh) since you can get a smaller or larger capacity and the unit will still run just either shorter or longer than expected. As long as the battery can physically fit in the unit you'll be fine but you have to match the voltage. The max current rating can be higher, but not lower.

As for tools, it looks like you'll need some small screwdrivers and a pry tool. Any precision toolkit should serve you well. Just be careful when inserting the pry tool so you don't cut any waterproofing seals. Though, don't expect it to be 'weatherproof' when you reassemble.

You shouldn't need an antistatic band but it's good to have one if you can get it. You will likely need to desolder the battery connections to the main PCB and resolder the replacement battery to the main PCB (Printed Circuit Board) or it could be connected via a [JST connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector). You won't know unless you get the full schematic or dismount.